# Django URL Regex not capturing Int

Tags: python, regex, django

I want to parse an integer to the url so I build my urls like this(there are 3 url because can have no arguments, the place or the place and an integer)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^map/$', geov.map_view, name = "map_view"),
    url(r'^map/(?P<search_place>[^\.]+)/$', geov.map_view, name = "map_view_accurate"),
    url(r'^map/(?P<search_place>[^\.]+)/(?P<digit>\d+)/$', geov.map_view),
]
```

So in my views I have:

```
def map_view(request, search_place = None, digit = 0):
    results = {}
    print(digit)
    if search_place is not None:
        query = Place_search.objects.filter(name_lower__icontains=search_place.lower()).order_by("-importance")
        results["query"] = query
    else:
        points = Place.objects.all()
        lon = points.count()

        results["points"]=points
        results["lon"] = lon

    return render_to_response("index.html", results)
```

But digit is always 0 and the query variable get no elements. If I just go  with the second url(Ex:"localhost:8000/map/madrid" it works correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second's url regexp catch what you want to catch by third url, i.e. search place with slash and digit, you should change it to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^map/$', geov.map_view, name = "map_view"),
    url(r'^map/(?P<search_place>[\w-]+)/$', geov.map_view, name = "map_view_accurate"),
    url(r'^map/(?P<search_place>[\w-]+)/(?P<digit>\d+)/$', geov.map_view),
]
```